# Sort string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of age groups:

```
["35 - 44", "18 - 34", "55+", "45 - 54"]
```

I want to sort it so that I have:

```
["18 - 34", "35 - 44", "45 - 54", "55+"]
```

What I have so far is:

```
arr.map(item => parseInt(item, 10)).sort((a, b) => a - b)
```

Which gives me:

```
[18, 25, 35, 65]
```

But I don't know what to do now with it.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't `map` it through `parseInt`, otherwise the non-numbers past the beginning of the string will be dropped. Just sort the plain array of strings with `localeCompare`:

```js
console.log(
  ["35 - 44", "18 - 34", "55+", "45 - 54"].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
);
```

To be a bit more flexible, if single-digit ranges exist too, use the `numeric: true` option as well:

```js
console.log(
  ["35 - 44", "1-2", "3-4", "18 - 34", "55+", "45 - 54"]
    .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true}))
);
```

Comment: That's what `{ numeric: true }` takes care of.

Comment: Sorry...missed that beyond the scrollbar ,